# Format String in Alias

Tags: unix

Unable to get the result I seek using the alias script below:

```
alias cfb="ps -eaf | grep PRD_ | egrep startscen.sh | awk '{print $2\"\t\"$14}'"
```

some sort of a format issue with \ - Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

`alias cfb=$(echo -e "ps -eaf | grep PRD_ | egrep startscen.sh | awk '{print \$2\"\t\"\$14}'")`

It's a bit difficult to test it without you saying 1) what is the result you seek, 2) providing a testable reproducible example.

Comment: This worked :D Clearly, I was struggling with the formatting there.